# Why is jquery animating my div size but failing to animate my text color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jQuery script is working to animate height and width of divs, but it is not animating the color of the text within those divs. Does anyone know why that is? I must be missing something really simple. I pasted the full code below, if that helps identify the problem. Line 9 and 12 are the ones that don't seem to be working.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".postit_family").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: "138",
      width: "150",
      left: "-=10",
      top: "-=9",
      'line-height': "132px"
    }, "fast");
    $("span").animate({
      color: "red"
    }, "fast");
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: "120",
      width: "130",
      left: "+=10",
      top: "+=9",
      'line-height': "118px"
    }, "fast");
    $("span").animate({
      color: "black"
    }, "fast");
  });
});
```

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#container {
  width: 780px;
  height: 673px;
  background-image: url("https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/Residuals/Images1/iMac.jpg");
  position: relative;
}

.postit_family {
  width: 130px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 118px;
  position: absolute;
}

.postit_family span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-align: center;
  color: #67768A;
  width: 90px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#postit_1 {
  left: 78px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#9DA0E0, #C9CAF2, #D5D6F5) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_2 {
  left: 242px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#A8A8A8, #E3E3E3, #FAFAFA) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_3 {
  left: 410px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#88DBBD, #CCEDE1, #DCF7ED) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_4 {
  left: 575px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#D1BF8C, #F5E2CE, #FAEFE3) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_5 {
  left: 78px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#EBBEBE, #F7D7E1, #FAE3EA) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_6 {
  left: 242px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#DAE3AA, #FAFCEB) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_7 {
  left: 410px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#5493D6, #7ECDE0, #B7E3ED) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_8 {
  left: 575px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#87CDD6, #E3F9FC) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>



<div id="container">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_1" class="postit_family"><span>Start Card</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_2" class="postit_family"><span>Invoice & Time Card Entry</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_3" class="postit_family"><span>Smart Products</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_4" class="postit_family"><span>Reports</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_5" class="postit_family"><span>Paycodes</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_6" class="postit_family"><span>System Guides</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_7" class="postit_family"><span>Occ Codes</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_8" class="postit_family"><span>Marcs</span></div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Consder adding a [mcve] to your question. The code you posted is nor complete, neither verifiable, which means we can't determine the cause of your problem. Which makes your question unanswerable. All we can do is guess at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work as expected is in the following line *(jQuery UI link)*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Change it to the following *(put `https` instead of `http`)* and it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

The reason why it wasn't working before is `Mixed Content`, that is the browser chose to ignore it, because it was loaded from an insecure source `http`, whereas the other resources are loaded through `https`.

This will be obvious to you, if you pay a look at your console. Here's a snapshot of what I see in mine:
[image]

**Snippet:**

```js
/* --- JavaScript --- */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".postit_family").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: "138",
      width: "150",
      left: "-=10",
      top: "-=9",
      'line-height': "132px"
    }, "fast");
    $("span").animate({
      color: "red"
    }, "fast");
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: "120",
      width: "130",
      left: "+=10",
      top: "+=9",
      'line-height': "118px"
    }, "fast");
    $("span").animate({
      color: "black"
    }, "fast");
  });
});
```

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#container {
  width: 780px;
  height: 673px;
  background-image: url("https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/Residuals/Images1/iMac.jpg");
  position: relative;
}

.postit_family {
  width: 130px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 118px;
  position: absolute;
}

.postit_family span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-align: center;
  color: #67768A;
  width: 90px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#postit_1 {
  left: 78px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#9DA0E0, #C9CAF2, #D5D6F5) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_2 {
  left: 242px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#A8A8A8, #E3E3E3, #FAFAFA) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_3 {
  left: 410px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#88DBBD, #CCEDE1, #DCF7ED) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_4 {
  left: 575px;
  top: 85px;
  background: linear-gradient(#D1BF8C, #F5E2CE, #FAEFE3) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_5 {
  left: 78px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#EBBEBE, #F7D7E1, #FAE3EA) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_6 {
  left: 242px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#DAE3AA, #FAFCEB) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_7 {
  left: 410px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#5493D6, #7ECDE0, #B7E3ED) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}

#postit_8 {
  left: 575px;
  top: 255px;
  background: linear-gradient(#87CDD6, #E3F9FC) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88D4E6, endColorstr=#307996);
  /* For IE 11*/
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_1" class="postit_family"><span>Start Card</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_2" class="postit_family"><span>Invoice & Time Card Entry</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_3" class="postit_family"><span>Smart Products</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_4" class="postit_family"><span>Reports</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_5" class="postit_family"><span>Paycodes</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_6" class="postit_family"><span>System Guides</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_7" class="postit_family"><span>Occ Codes</span></div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="postit_8" class="postit_family"><span>Marcs</span></div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: brilliant, now it works. You're right, the 's' was missing from the url, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @shampouya.